# wlan0 disappears after shutting down VM

Tags: kali-linux, network-interface, wlan

Yesterday I got a tp-link TL-WN722N. I managed to set it up correctly, and it worked fine until I shut down the VM and started it up again. wlan0 had disappeared and when I tried to set the adapter up again I got the error: `rmmod: ERROR: Module r8188eu is not currently loaded`. I could not get it to work again, so I reinstalled Kali Linux and tried again, which worked. However, now I get the same error after shutting down.

I am new to this so maybe I have missed something. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm running Kali Linux 2022.2 on macOS using VMware Fusion.

Comment: You'll have to give much more information, starting by telling what kind of OS is the host and what is the hypervisor in use. If it's Windows chances are this question should be on an other Stackexchange site.

Comment: @A.B I'm running Kali Linux 2022.2 on macOS using VMware Fusion

Answer (score 3):

Most WiFi driver modules are autoloaded as the WiFi adapter is detected, so the module not being loaded indicates the Linux kernel has not been able to see the hardware after the restart.

In the comments, you said you're running Kali Linux 2022.2 on macOS VMware Fusion. So, a common cause for error like this is that the VM is not configured to always take control of the WiFi adapter from the host OS and turn it over to the VM every time the VM is started. So it is likely to be a VMware configuration issue, not a Linux issue.

Instead, the WiFi set-up instructions you have been following apparently include a step that transfers the control of the WiFi adapter to the VM *for one run of the VM only*.

After setting up the VM once, the WiFi adapter returns to macOS control as soon as you shut down the VM, but the rest of the setup should still be there. But without persistently assigning the WiFi adapter to the VM, you will need to do that step again each time you start the VM.

You could automate this. In VMware Fusion terminology, it's called [setting the default plug-in action](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/12/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-441678E9-138C-44E1-AC41-F3C27A384652.html) for your USB WiFi adapter.

If the WiFi adapter is already plugged in before starting the VM, macOS will still take control of it. In this situation, you might still need to manually assign it to the VM, as VMware might see that macOS is already using it and not reassign it without explicit user confirmation; the VMware documentation seems unclear on this and I don't have VMware Fusion at hand for testing.